# Missing constructor for DialogPreference

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm in the process of converting a project to Kotlin. When I converted the Dialog Preferences, the app crashed with a "no such method", apparently the constructor is missing. This is the error message:

```
05-26 20:13:32.799  6019  6019 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
05-26 20:13:32.799  6019  6019 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2204)
05-26 20:13:32.799  6019  6019 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1683)
05-26 20:13:32.799  6019  6019 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.preference.GenericInflater.createItem(GenericInflater.java:378)
```

The class has the 2 argument constructor the error message complains about:

```
class FilterPreferenceFragment(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    BaseDialogPreference(context, attrs) {
    /* */
}
```

And the base class:

```
abstract class BaseDialogPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    DialogPreference(context, attrs) {
    /* */
}
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:

in case it is helpful, here's the bytecode generated by the Kotlin compiler:

```
  // access flags 0x1
  public <init>(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull;() // invisible, parameter 0
    @Lorg/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable;() // invisible, parameter 1
   L0
    ALOAD 1
    LDC "context"
    INVOKESTATIC kotlin/jvm/internal/Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull (Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
   L1
    LINENUMBER 12 L1
    ALOAD 0
    ALOAD 1
    ALOAD 2
   L2
    LINENUMBER 13 L2
    INVOKESPECIAL android/preference/DialogPreference.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
    RETURN
   L3
    LOCALVARIABLE this Lcom/example/exampleapp/app/preference/BaseDialogPreference; L0 L3 0
    LOCALVARIABLE context Landroid/content/Context; L0 L3 1
    LOCALVARIABLE attrs Landroid/util/AttributeSet; L0 L3 2
    MAXSTACK = 3
    MAXLOCALS = 3

  @Lkotlin/Metadata;(mv={1, 1, 6}, bv={1, 0, 1}, k=1, d1={"\u0000$\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0002\u0008\u0002\n\u0002\u0010\u0002\n\u0000\n\u0002\u0018\u0002\n\u0000\u0008&\u0018\u00002\u00020\u0001B\u0017\u0012\u0006\u0010\u0002\u001a\u00020\u0003\u0012\u0008\u0010\u0004\u001a\u0004\u0018\u00010\u0005\u00a2\u0006\u0002\u0010\u0006J\u0010\u0010\u0007\u001a\u00020\u00082\u0006\u0010\u0009\u001a\u00020\nH\u0014\u00a8\u0006\u000b"}, d2={"Lcom/example/exampleapp/app/preference/BaseDialogPreference;", "Landroid/preference/DialogPreference;", "context", "Landroid/content/Context;", "attrs", "Landroid/util/AttributeSet;", "(Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V", "onBindView", "", "view", "Landroid/view/View;", "production sources for module ExampleApp"})
  // compiled from: BaseDialogPreference.kt
```

Comment: you need to use secondary constructor in kotlin DialogPreference class contain multiple constructor. for more information about secondary constructor. 
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html

Comment: What should the signature of this secondary constructor be?

Comment: ahh sorry for that. i try it and its run you forget to add ? in context. context are also null-able so add ? after Context? and its works .
for example 
open class B(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : DialogPreference(context, attrs)

Comment: Are you using ProGuard or any other tools which transform your bytecode and may strip this constructor?

Comment: @mcd: I tried that, but it didn't make a difference. Makes sense though that it didn't change, Context is not nullable, a view must always be attached to a context.

Comment: @Miha_x64 no, it's a debug build, proguard is not running.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I was looking at the wrong class. The error came from this other preference:

```
class BaseCheckBoxPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : CheckBoxPreference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) { /* */ }
```

To solve the crash I had to remove the 3rd argument from the constructor:

```
class BaseCheckBoxPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : CheckBoxPreference(context, attrs) { /* */ }
```

Alternatively, we can define a secondary constructor that only takes 2 arguments, but for my use case I only needed the one with 2 arguments. The secondary constructor would be

```
class BaseCheckBoxPreference(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : CheckBoxPreference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null) : this(context, attrs, 0)

/* */
}
```